# MySQL Select Query for taking data within specific time in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have below two tables in pasted scree shot, 
Query with these table is fine for me to take data for last 24 hrs as this will give me 1st device in the table.

now I need new query that 2nd device in T1 also should come because this device create time in T1 is within 24 hrs of T2 insert time.

3rd device in T1 should not come in my query result because its create time in T1 is greater than 24 hrs than insert time in T2.

I am looking query for the last two points.

```
Select a.device,[a.create time], b.device, [b.insert time] 
from T1 a, T2 b 
where a.device = b.device and a.time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: I needs to write new query which will give 1st and 2nd device also, Currently I am able only to find 1st device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a.device = b.device` should be your join condition.

```
Select a.device,[a.create time], b.device, [b.insert time] 
from T1 a inner join T2 b on a.device = b.device
where 
    a.time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) --first condtion
    or a.time <= DATE_SUB(b.time, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) --second condition
```